# generate literal union type for all possible alphabetical letters ("a" | "b" | ... | "z")

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Is there a more elegant way (with recursive type definition maybe?) to get the same result : a "Letter" type with all possible lowercase letters as literal type union?

```js
const alphabet = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"] as const

type Letter = typeof alphabet[number]
```

Comment: what is wrong with `typeof alphabet[number]` way?

Comment: Not yet https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15480

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi nothing wrong but is just for fun ...

Comment: I don't think there's anything more "elegant" (although this is subjective).  You pretty much need string literal types containing all the characters you need; you can't currently "generate" them.  You can have fun extracting all the letters from a string literal like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NBPVzW), but fun ≠ elegant.